# Migrating tt_news to news: Plugin Migration creates textmedia plugins

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news, typo3-extensions, tt-news

I'm in the process of migrating a TYPO3 7 LTS latest site from ext:tt_news to ext:news.

The data migration is working flawless. But when I'm running `ttnewspluginmigrate:run`, all new plugins are textmedia content elements (should be news content elements).

What I tried solving this issue:

- Updated tt_news to latest version on TER
- Used dev:master of news_ttnewsimport
- Used dev:master of news
- Used ^5.0 for news

The site is heavily reliant on tt_news plugins, so manually replacing them would rather be unpleasant.

**Data migration working, plugin migration failing**

Additional Information:

- Template uses fsc, csc extension disabled

Answer (score 1):

The migration is not that complicated to debug and I wonder why that could happen. See https://github.com/ext-news/news_ttnewsimport/blob/master/Classes/Service/Migrate/TtNewsPluginMigrate.php#L84-L85

Can you check the database what is wrong with the new elements? The field `CType` should be `list` and the field `list_type` should be `news_pi1`.

Comment: Georg, thanks for the fast response. CType is textmedia and list_type is empty. This is the generated query: https://pastebin.com/YHUVHGNX

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm exactly the same problem. Same conditions – 7 LTS, fsc, no csc. So I tried to investigate. UPDATE query for this textmedia record was generated, but without any effect.

Then i tried it manually and i got following error: "**Unknown column 'header_position' in 'field list**'". So it is obvious – tt_content table with FSC (Fluid Styled Content) used instead of CSC, doesn't contain "header_position" field. The same goes also for fields "spaceBefore", "spaceAfter" and "section_frame". So these fields should be excluded from "$fieldToCopy" in case of using FSC.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).